# Download attachment from Outlook using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com

I am trying to download attachments from Outlook using Python, as of now am able to download the attachments by subject line but in my case I want to download multiple attachments from multiple emails where subject line starts with some string, For Ex:
Subjects are: Query 123654, Query 56975, Query 5698 like this and I want to download all of them where subject name starts with "Query".
My current code is below:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
val_date = datetime.date.today()

sub_today = 'Query 123654'
att_today = ''
for msg in all_inbox:
    if msg.Subject == sub_today and msg.Senton.date() == val_date:
        break

for att in msg.Attachments:
    if att.FileName == att_today:
        break

try:
    att.SaveAsFile('C:\\Offline Feeds\\Attachments' + '\\'+ att.FileName)
    messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESSFUL","Attachments Downloaded")
except:
    messagebox.showerror("ERROR","Attachment Download Failed")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use find() to search  specific data.

```
sub_today = 'Query'

if msg.Subject.find(sub_today) != -1 break
```

If subject not include “Query”, it will return “-1”.

This is the complete code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
val_date = datetime.date.today()

sub_today = 'Query'
att_today = ''
for msg in all_inbox:
    if msg.Subject.find(sub_today) != -1 and msg.Senton.date() == val_date:
        break

for att in msg.Attachments:
    if att.FileName == att_today:
        break

try:
    att.SaveAsFile('C:\\Offline Feeds\\Attachments' + '\\'+ att.FileName)
    messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESSFUL","Attachments Downloaded")
except:
    messagebox.showerror("ERROR","Attachment Download Failed")
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Python String find() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm)

Comment: thanks for the modification @Alina Li but
     if msg.Subject.find(sub_today) != -1 and msg.Senton.date() == val_date:
 is not working as expected(downloading all attachments which starts with 'Query') instead it is only downloading the attachment of email which has been sent first out of multiple emails.

Comment: You could try  search_result = msg.Subject.find(sub_today)     if msg.Senton.date() == val_date and search_result != -1:   break

Comment: This code is not working and raising an error "AttributeError: <unknown>.Senton" I even tried "if sub_today in msg.Subject and msg.Senton.date() == val_date: break" but its downloading the first email's attch not of all. I even tried the nested for loop to run it for multiple times but no change.